# SelectPDF ConvertUrl Non-English Characters Error

Tags: c#, html-to-pdf, selectpdf

In my demo project I'm using [Selectpdf](https://selectpdf.com/) tool to convert html pages to pdf documents. These html pages are stored locally. So I'm using ConvertUrl function for conversion. Here is the inline code
`

```
string url = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "HTML" + "\\OrderName_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'_'HH'-'mm_") + MockOrderNo + ".html";

HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();
PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertUrl(htmlurl);
```

`
Then I save the pdf document, using doc.Save(). Here is the pdf document result
[image]

Now as you can see there is a problem displaying Turkish characters like "İ,ı,ş,ğ...". How can I resolve this using SelectPdf? If solving this with SelectPdf is not possible, what are the other prefable pdf conversion tools that does not have this kind of problem?

Also for my requirements I don't use ConvertHtmlString function. I need to store html pages in a folder, convert these html pages to pdf and store those pdf documents in an another folder.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the encoding of html file to windows-1252. This solved the problem